# Does an open wound make one unfit to lay Tefillin?

Tags: tefilin, health-safety-shmira, blood, personal-hygiene

In order to be fit to wear Tefillin one must have a guf naki, a clean body (Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chayyim 37:2) . Suppose one has an open wound or sore on one's skin and it is actively bleeding or oozing a bodily discharge. Would someone in such a state have an unclean body, as far as laying Tefillin is concerned?

Comment: If your wound is bleeding, I would recommend putting a bandage on it or getting it stitched long before you need to worry about putting on Tefillin!

Comment: @DanF There may be a "bandage" there already and the question still holds. Consider the case of menstruation.

Comment: I believe regular blood is entirely different, in regards to Tumah.

Comment: @WhyEnBe Yes, but that kind of technical-Tumah (the kind from Seder Tohorot) is probably irrelevant here, considering that feces and flatulence are relevant and neither has anything to do with technical-Tumah.

Comment: @DoubleAA Re *niddah*, see O.C. 88.

Comment: @DanF A side concern, which as noted there is not practiced by all. Accd to the OP though we might have a universally accepted formal issue.

Comment: @DoubleAA What's your take on http://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Eruvin.96a.43?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all? There's a small section where Tosfot mentions that women don't wear tefillin b/c they are not careful of "guf naki" - no explanation why. Could it be b/c of menstruation / oozing blood?